# SQL Server insert table column to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Is it possible to insert to stored procedure a table column from a not declared in any joins? For example,

```
SELECT
    a.employee, b.department, a.time <= dbo.table_name.column 
FROM
    NGAC_AUTHLOG AS a 
INNER JOIN
    NGAC_USERINFO AS b ON a.ID = b.UserID
```

All I get is this error, 'The multi-part identifier "..." could not be bound.'. Is there a way calling a database table column without using the join?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes - in a sub query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.employee, b.department, (case when a.time <= (select top 1 column from dbo.table_name) then 'True' else 'False' end) TrueOrNot
FROM
    NGAC_AUTHLOG AS a 
INNER JOIN
    NGAC_USERINFO AS b ON a.ID = b.UserID
```